# Numpy array aggregation in slice/vectorized notation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Using np, how to create a new numpy array that is a combination of 2 numpy arrays?

Here is the problem:

```
x = [[a1,a2],[b1,b2],...] # this is an ndarray
y = [a,b,c,...] # ditto

xnew = [[a1,a2,a],...]
```

or `xnew = [([a1,a2],a), ...]`

Here is how I would solve it using lists and for loops:

```
xnew = [(x[i],y[i]) for i in range(len(x))]
```

How do I do the same thing using numpy?

Comment: `np.column_stack((x,y))`?

Comment: nice, thanks man. is there a way to make it a tuple? stack just adds the column.  Y can be an arbitrary length list, as can X, so I need to keep them separate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is straight forward case of concatenation - except that `y` needs to be transposed:

```
In [246]: x = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
In [247]: y= np.array([[5,6]])
In [248]: np.concatenate((x,y.T),axis=1)
Out[248]: 
array([[1, 2, 5],
       [3, 4, 6]])
```

That is, in one way or other `y` has to have as many rows as `x`.  `column_stack` and `hstack` require the same transpose.

In `numpy`, tuple notation is used for structured array records.  That requires defining a compound `dtype`.  If you outline the desired `dtype`, I can help you construct it.

You comment:

> Y can be an arbitrary length list, as can X, so I need to keep them separate..

Does that mean there can be different number of items in Y and X, and that some of those tuples will in complete?  Having a x term but not y, or v.v.?  If that's the case, then you'd be test of using list comprehension and one of the `zip` tools (regular zip or one from `itertools`).  numpy arrays are for lists/arrays that match in size.

zip examples:

```
In [263]: x = [[1,2],[3,4]]
In [264]: y= [5,6,7]         # not nested
```

zip over the shortest, ignore the longest

```
In [266]: [(i,j) for i,j in zip(x,y)]
Out[266]: [([1, 2], 5), ([3, 4], 6)]
```

zip over the longest, pad the shortest

```
In [267]: [(i,j) for i,j in itertools.zip_longest(x,y)]
Out[267]: [([1, 2], 5), ([3, 4], 6), (None, 7)]
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you.  (the compound dtype isn't necessary... I figured out I would be able to handle Y matrices with lists of different length further down the line--during my distance calcs and averages, it works out that all the X values get turned into a single value and only the Ys are left)